# How to Use DataBase with senchaTouch

Tags: database, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i am working with Sencha touch application like multiple choice Questions Quiz.
in sencha touch there is model-store concept,but i want to use database like Sqlite for Questions and answers.
so, is there any way to use database in Sencha toch ?
or can we make queries for databas operation ? 
any help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 local storage using a `LocalStorage` proxy.  See the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage

If you have a lot of info to store and want a bigger database that isn't on the client side, you will need to run a server app of your choosing, and connect your Sencha Touch app to that server using Ajax or JSON-P calls.

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```
var db = openDatabase('yourDBName', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS POSITION (id unique, positionValue)');
});

var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO POSITION (id, positionValue) VALUES ("+"'"+id+"'"+","+"'"+"CUR"+"'"+")";
            tx.executeSql(insertQuery);
```

executeSql method support all sql queries .